# How to test if two files are identical via mocha

Tags: node.js, file, diff, mocha.js

I have written a node.js script which scans a very large legacy code base and applies a set of changes.

The changes can be quite complex because this affects certain storage mechanisms and associated size definitions.

I've written tests that all the calculations and reporting is correct by using mocha, chai and sinon. '

Now I'm attempting to write a test that applies the changes to 20 samples of the legacy source. I can create a version of the 20 samples with the correct changes, I just want my test to compare the applied changes to the predicted changes.

So in essence the test is a diff between file `A` and file `B`, where the results should be that the files are identical. Google is showing a lot of results on array, string and object diffs. Does anyone have a solution of how to do this for files?

I should note that I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel. I've experimented with `prettydiff`, with something along the lines of:

```
prettydiff({source: processedFile, diff: expectedFile, lang: 'text'}).should.equal("Number of differences: 0 differences from 0 lines of text.");
```

I've also tried:

```
expect(prettydiff({source: processedFile, diff: expectedFile, lang: 'text'})).to.equal("Number of differences: 0 differences from 0 lines of text.");
```

However all I get in both cases is an error stating `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.

What is the correct way to test a diff of two files using mocha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a tad more complex than I expected.

With the help of sctskw, we determined that the first problem was using the `prettydiff` api incorrectly. Unfortunately it didn't resolve how to diff two files within node.js.

The libs that I found only accept strings to perform a diff.

`prettydiff` adds a lot of html content to the results, such that you're forced to redirect the output to a file and view the results in a browser. Not really suitable if you wish to analyse the results programatically.

`jsdiff` reports on every single line, with a couple of variables per line to determine if it's a new line or a removed line.

In both cases the files must be read first. So common code for both approaches is as follows:

```
var fs = require ('fs');

var source = "";
var target = "";

try {
  source = fs.readFileSync('a.txt', 'utf8');
} catch(e) {
  console.error("error reading a.txt: " + e.message);
  return;
}

try {
  target = fs.readFileSync('b.txt', 'utf8');
} catch(e) {
  console.error("error reading a.txt: " + e.message);
  return;
}
```

To test the files in [prettydiff](https://github.com/prettydiff/prettydiff) perform the following:

```
var prettydiff = require('prettydiff');

output = prettydiff.api({
  source: source, 
  mode: 'diff',
  diff: target, 
  lang: 'text',
});

console.log(output[0]);
```

Just make sure that you redirect the output to a file when you run it, view the results in the browser of your choice.

To test the files in [jsdff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) perform the following:

```
var diff = require('diff');
var results = diff.diffLines(source, target);
var identical = true;

results.forEach(function(part) {
  if(part.added) {
    console.log("added:   " + part.value);
    identical = false;
  }
  if(part.removed) {
    console.log("removed: " + part.value);
    identical = false;
  }
});

console.log("Identical? " + identical);
```

Obviously the code isn't the most efficient and a smarter approach could be taken in handling the files instead of using sync right now, but the examples clearly demonstrate how to diff files within node.js.

The second one is useful if you wish to process the results programatically and is the only simple way to determine if the files are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this module? Or something like it?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff

From their api docs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettydiff

```
var prettydiff = require("prettydiff"),
    args       = {
        source: "asdf",
        diff  : "asdd",
        lang  : "text"
    },
    output     = prettydiff.api(args);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of the diff lib. However I'm looking for how to test the difference within `mocha `.

Comment: I don't understand the difference? You simply require this library in your mocha tests and assert the output?

Comment: In my question I show that I'm doing just that, asserting the results from prettydiff, a node.js lib that does a diff between two files. However when I do this, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`. I'm doing something wrong, just not sure what. I thought my problem was clear, maybe I need to create an example stub and post the full code.

Comment: My guess is prettyDiff wasn't required in your module or you're not using their api properly

Comment: Just creating a test case now and looks like your second guess is correct.

Comment: Thanks for that @sctskw. I've tested it but while it solved my initial problem, unfortunately it didn't solve my question (as I had phrased it). I could have deleted my question or changed my question. However I thought it more useful to provide a working solution to the original question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Another easy way, although not full proof is to convert your file to a long string and test their equality and length. There would be a few edge cases obviously but not that hard to solve with string replacement depending on how "equal" they need to be

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running `Pretty Diff` from the command line with the *diffcli* option?

When I run:

> node api/node-local.js source:"prettydiff.js" diff:"prettydiff.js" mode:"diff" diffcli:"true"

The command line reports:

> Pretty Diff found 0 differences in 1 files out of 1 file. Executed in 0.058 seconds.

There is some documentation about this:
http://prettydiff.com/guide/diffcli.xhtml